# type hinting, class inheritance and metaclass with a cython lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, type-hinting, pygrib

I am using a `cython` lib called `pygrib` that doesn't have any associated type hinting.

I would like to extend its features by wrapping, for example the `pygrib.open` method in some classes with relative type hints.

`pygrib.open` returns an `Iterator` with `pygrib.messages`

#### the classes

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Iterator, Type, List
import pygrib

class GrbMessage:
    def keys(self) -> List[str]: ...


class GrbMeta(Type, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[GrbMessage]: ...


class GrbOpen(pygrib.open, metaclass=GrbMeta):
    ...
```

#### usage

If I explicitly state by using the `change_type` function that the variable is `GrbMeta` the `VSCode` `ide` detects the type hinting.

```
def change_type(x)->GrbMeta:
    return x

def _unzip(path: str) -> str:
    os.system(f'gzip -d {path}')
    return path.strip('.gz')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grbs = GrbOpen(_unzip(GRIB_FILE))
    typed_grbs = change_type(grbs)

    for grb in grbs:
        grb.keys()

    for grb in typed_grbs:
        grb.keys()
```

[image: TypeHints]

A **possible solution** is to just return self from the from `__iter__`

#### possible solution

```py
class GrbOpen(pygrib.open):

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[GrbMessage]:
        return self
```

<s>I'm just curious if this could be done better.</s>

Why does `GrbOpen(pygrib.open, metaclass=GrbMeta)` not inherit the `GrbMeta` typehints

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you *asking*? Can *what* be done better – using a wrapper, annotation the library, or something else?

Comment: Are you aware that you can provide type hints for existing libraries via `.pyi` files?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why `class GrbOpen(pygrib.open, metaclass=GrbMeta):` does not inherit the `GrbMeta` typehints.  I have not used .pyi files before I'll have to dig into that.

Answer (score 0):

It's often the process of asking a question that brings me to a solution.

Creating the `NewType` seems to have achieved what I was trying to accomplish.

```
GribFileType = NewType("GribFile", GribFileType)

class GribFile(pygrib.open):

    def to_dataframe(self: GribFileType):
        return pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict(_full_message(grb)) for grb in self)


class Reader:
    """reader wrapper with typing support around the pygrib open function"""
    grib_file: GribFile

    def __init__(self, file_path: str):
        if file_path.endswith('.gz'):
            self.file_path = _unzip(file_path)
        else:
            self.file_path = file_path

    def __enter__(self) -> GribFileType:
        self.grib_file = GribFile(self.file_path)
        return self.grib_file

    @abstractmethod
    def __exit__(self, *args) -> None:
        self.grib_file.close()
```